# Validate model even when invalid parse

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to code basic date field validator.

So I've created a directive with custom date `$validator`. And all was fine. When `$validator` doesn't pass I got error. But now I need to force field to automatically convert value to date data type, so I wrote custom `$parser`.

Now I have a situation when my `$validator` not hit untill `$parser` is valid.

**My goal is to have `date type` output and to rise `ng-invalid-date` on date like `33.33.3333`.**

Here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/y3ZCWUjCUOYEm1Cea2WE?p=preview

Comment: Why do you use a input of type `text`? Just use a input of type `date` and you will be fine.

Comment: @lin hmm... maybe because it's supported only by Edge, Chrome and Opera? Or maybe because I need a custom date picker on this field? :) Or maybe I need to style the field the way I like? So, how should I be fine?

Comment: `return new Date('33.33.3333') !== 'Invalid Date'` ?

Comment: What do you mean? From where?

Answer (score 0):

It is seems that only returning of `undefined` from `$parsers` brakes the `$validators` chain. Returning of empty string proceed with validation.